# How to sum all the elements (except for the first one) in rows in 2d list?

Tags: python, list

So, my task is to write a program which gets an integer  on the input, then  times asks for the student's name (one word) and a space-separated list of their grades, and on the output there should be a list of tuples, where each tuple consists of the student's name and their grade point average, rounded to integers.

**Example:**

Input:

3

Ann 5 6 7 8

Ben 10 10 0 0

Fred 7 6 8 5

Output:

[('Ann', 6), ('Ben', 5), ('Fred', 6)]

Now my program looks like this:

```
n = int(input())
a = list()
for i in range(n):
  a.append(input().split())
print(tuple(a))
```

I have no idea how to sum numbers in each row (except for the first string, student's name) and make it like a new list. Maybe I should somehow use numpy in this case, but still don't know how. I will be grateful for any help

Comment: `range()` takes up to three parameters, namely `range(start, stop, step)`. You can use `range(n, 1)` to loop to n-1, starting at index 1. More on [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: Let's define `entry = input().split()` ; `name = entry[0]`  and `grades = entry[1:]` is the list of grades in string format; you can do `sum(int(grade) for grade in grades)` and divide by `len(grades)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- After splitting each line on a space, the first element of the result is the name, and the rest of the elements are the grades.
- Use `sum` to get the total of all grades, then divide by the number of grades to get the average.

```py
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
  name, *grades = input().split()
  a.append((name, round(sum(map(int, grades)) / len(grades))))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `a` and for each sublist, create a tuple out of the first item and the mean of the remaining items.  You can use the built-in `statistics.mean` and then convert its result to an `int`:

```
from statistics import mean

n = int(input())
a = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
result = [
    (name, int(mean(float(s) for s in scores)))
    for name, *scores in a
]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, it was useful, but on some tests it didn't round the numbers correctly